# Jquery Toggle Dropdown Menu On Click

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, fade

I have a menu with three links. Upon clicking "One", the first link, a dropdown menu appears. Same goes for clicking "Two", and "Three".

How can I get "sub-one" to fade out when "sub-two" is active?

```
<div id="navi">

<div id="one"> 
    <a href="#">one</a> 
</div>    

 <div id="two"> 
    <a href="#">two</a> 
</div>    

 <div id="three"> 
    <a href="#">three</a> 
  </div>    
 </div>

  <div id="sub-one">
      <a href="#"> <p> one </p> </a>
      <a href="#"> <p> two </p> </a>
  </div>

  <div id="sub-two">
      <a href="#"> <p> thre </p> </a>
      <a href="#"> <p> four </p> </a>
  </div>

  <div id="sub-three">
      <a href="#"> <p> five </p> </a>
      <a href="#"> <p> six </p> </a>
  </div>
```

**Complete code** - [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/5fvpq5vk/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your approach to fade all them out by default. Then fade in your target

```
$(document).ready(
      function() {
        $("#one, #two, #three").click(function() {
          var id = $(this).attr('id');
          $('[id^="sub"]').fadeOut();
          $("#sub-" + id).fadeIn();
        });
      });
```

```js
$(document).ready(
   function() {
     $("#one, #two, #three").click(function() {
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       $('[id^="sub"]').fadeOut();
          if($("#sub-" + id).is(':visible')){
            $("#sub-" + id).fadeOut();
          }
          else{
            $("#sub-" + id).fadeIn();
            }
       
     });
   });
```

```css
#navi {
   font-family: 'Roboto', Helvetica, Sans-serif;
   font-size: 12px;
   letter-spacing: 4px;
   color: black;
   font-weight: 600;
   position: fixed;
   height: 100px;
   float: right;
   text-align: right;
   right: 10%;
   top: 11%;
   min-width: 10%;
 }
 #navi a {
   color: black;
   padding: 0 0 0 5px;
 }
 #one,
 #two,
 #three {
   float: left;
   padding-left: 5px;
 }
 #sub-one,
 #sub-two,
 #sub-three {
   display: none;
   font-family: 'Roboto', Helvetica, Sans-serif;
   font-size: 12px;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   color: black;
   font-weight: 400;
   position: absolute;
   float: right;
   text-align: right;
   right: 10%;
   top: 15%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navi">

  <div id="one">
    <a href="#">one</a> 
  </div>

  <div id="two">
    <a href="#">two</a> 
  </div>

  <div id="three">
    <a href="#">three</a> 
  </div>
</div>

<div id="sub-one">
  <a href="#">
    <p>one</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <p>two</p>
  </a>
</div>

<div id="sub-two">
  <a href="#">
    <p>thre</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <p>four</p>
  </a>
</div>

<div id="sub-three">
  <a href="#">
    <p>five</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <p>six</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I have the sub-menu fadeout once clicking it's parent menu item?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fvpq5vk/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="sub" id="sub-one">
    <a href="#"> <p> one </p> </a>
    <a href="#"> <p> two </p> </a>
</div>

<div class="sub" id="sub-two">
    <a href="#"> <p> thre </p> </a>
    <a href="#"> <p> four </p> </a>
</div>

<div class="sub" id="sub-three">
    <a href="#"> <p> five </p> </a>
    <a href="#"> <p> six </p> </a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function fadeOutAll(){
    $(".sub").fadeOut();    
}


$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("#one").click(function() {
            fadeOutAll()
            $("#sub-one").fadeToggle();
        });
    });
```

Comment: I'd like the sub-menu items to fade out when clicking on their parent menu item (once they are already faded in). Can you help?

Comment: you have already accepted above answer. Didn't it work for you ?